# How do I capitalise the last letter of each word in a sentence in PHP?

Tags: php, function, foreach

This is the starting point I've been given:

```
<?php

function capitaliseLastLetterOfEachWord( $string ){

    return $string;

}

echo capitaliseLastLetterOfEachWord("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");

?>
```

This is as far as I got and it gave me the last letters of each word in uppercase:

```
<?php

function capitaliseLastLetterOfEachWord( $string ){

    $separate = explode(" ", $string);

    foreach($separate as $word) {
        $lastword = $word[strlen($word) - 1 ];
        echo strtoupper($lastword) . "<br>";
    }
}

echo capitaliseLastLetterOfEachWord("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"); 

?>
```

Comment: indent your code next time, paste/highlight all, CTRL-K, save, *done like dinner* ;-)

Comment: And what is a question?

Comment: Thanks Fred, I will keep a note.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function capitaliseLastLetterOfEachWord( $string ){
    return strrev(ucwords(strrev($string)));
}
```

Steps:

1. reverse the string
2. use ucwords to capitalise the first letter of each reversed word
3. reverse the string back again

If you want to remove any existing capitalistion first, change it to this

`return strrev(ucwords(strrev(strtolower($string))));`

Comment: Thank you rjdown! that's brilliant :)

Answer (score 2):

The others already gave the short way, just to explain what you're doing right now, you're just making changes to the last string and not returning it. You'll need to target the last character then make the changes, just `&` add a reference into the foreach then don't forget to **return** the values:

```
$lastword = $word[strlen($word) - 1 ];
// you're not returning and appending your changes

<?php

function capitaliseLastLetterOfEachWord( $string ){
    $separate = explode(" ", strtotlower($string));
    foreach($separate as &$word) { // add reference
        $word[strlen($word) - 1] = strtoupper($word[strlen($word) - 1]);        
        //   point to it ^ ,       the change ^
    }
    return implode(' ', $separate); // don't forget to return
}

echo capitaliseLastLetterOfEachWord("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
```

Comment: I wasn't sure where I was going with my attempt but it's great that you've explained it to me, I appreciate it, thank you :)